# Right outer join in hql giving unexpected token for and condition

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, outer-join

I am using hibernate 3.0.
I am applying the right outer join. my query is

```
List<Integer> phaseCount1 = getHibernateTemplate().find("select count(phasesPlan.phaseid.id) as Phase from PhasePlan phasesPlan RIGHT JOIN " +
            "phasesPlan.phaseid as phasedetails and phasesPlan.teamid.teamid=? group by phasedetails.id",team_id);
```

in this the and condition ( `phasesPlan.phaseid as phasedetails **and** phasesPlan.teamid.teamid=?` ) is giving unexpected token exception.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to replace "and" with "where" :-

```
find("select count(phasesPlan.phaseid.id) as Phase 
from PhasePlan phasesPlan RIGHT JOIN " +
    "phasesPlan.phaseid as phasedetails **where** phasesPlan.teamid.teamid=? 
group by phasedetails.id",team_id)
```

Comment: But where is not serving my purpose, when where is applied i am  not getting the query result as right join.

Comment: In this case, we need to specify on which column the join should be :-find("select count(phasesPlan.phaseid.id) as Phase from PhasePlan phasesPlan RIGHT JOIN " + "phasesPlan.phaseid as phasedetails on phasesPlan.teamid.teamid=phasedetails.teamid where phasesPlan.teamid.teamid=? group by phasedetails.id",team_id)

Comment: This is not working.Hibernate doesn not accept 'on' i.e. phasesPlan.phaseid as phasedetails on phasesPlan.teamid.teamid=phasedetails.teamid is giving error

Comment: Can u try "with" instead of "on" and "and" instead of "where"

Comment: U can also try the options @ http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins

Comment: and is not acceptable without where.. This was the original problem